# Filter Records from SQLite to show in a List

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have some data in **SQLite** database, which I would like to show in a `List` based on small logic.

I have three fields in my table,

```
first field : id
second field : title
third field : type
```

where **Type** can be : `Monthly` or `Yearly`

Here is my code:

```
    // Generate real data for each item
    public List<ReminderItem> generateData(int count) {
        ArrayList<ReminderItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

        // Get all reminders from the database
        List<Reminder> reminders = rb.getAllReminders();

        // Initialize lists
        List<String> Titles = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> Type = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> IDList= new ArrayList<>();

        // Add details of all reminders in their respective lists
        for (Reminder r : reminders) {
            Titles.add(r.getTitle());
            Type.add(r.getType());
            IDList.add(r.getID());
        }
        return items;
      }
```

This is the situation, where I need help from you guys, As you can see still, I am showing each and `every record` from **database to list**, no matter from which **Type** it belongs.

Now, I just want to show `records` in a `List`, which belongs to Type **"Monthly"** only

So exactly what I have to do ? How can I show records in a List for the Type of "Monthly" only

I have a `String` variable namely, **strType = "Monthly";**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two option to do this.

> First is directly get only those record from database which reminder type is "Monthly" by execute below sql statement.

```
SELECT id,title,type FROM table_name WHERE type = "Monthly"
```

> Second is check reminder type is equal to "Monthly" when you add data into List.

```
for (Reminder r : reminders) {

        String reminderType = r.getType();
        if(reminderType.equalsIgnoreCase(strType)) {

            Titles.add(r.getTitle());
            Type.add(reminderType);
            IDList.add(r.getID());
        }
    }
```

**Full Code**

```
// Generate real data for each item
public List<ReminderItem> generateData(int count) {

    String strType = "Monthly";

    ArrayList<ReminderItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    // Get all reminders from the database
    List<Reminder> reminders = rb.getAllReminders();

    // Initialize lists
    List<String> Titles = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> Type = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> IDList= new ArrayList<>();

    // Add details of all reminders which type="Monthly" in their respective lists
    for (Reminder r : reminders) {

        String reminderType = r.getType();
        if(reminderType.equalsIgnoreCase(strType)) {

            Titles.add(r.getTitle());
            Type.add(reminderType);
            IDList.add(r.getID());
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @HirendrasinhS.Rathod

Answer (score 0):

When you select from your sqlite db you can add filter there

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_A + " WHERE " + 
COLUMN_TYPE + "=?", new String[]{ arg0 }); // arg0 = "Monthly"
```

This will increase your performance instead of filtering List after load